# No entry is registered for key in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am quite new to Zend.I am trying to fetch the data from a config file in zend framework V1. My code is

```
public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $config = Zend_Registry::get('configPage');
        ..........................................
    }
```

The error is "No entry is registered for key 'configPage'".

I have created a folder called configs and a file config.ini under configs folder. The folder is residing under Application/admin-modules/pages/configs

Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Bootstrap class you must register the config using :

```
protected function _initConfigs()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions(), true);
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    return $config;
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config')->configPage;
    ..........................................
}
```